# Using @set entries in biber --> No author display in second entry

Tags: biblatex, biber, author-number

I'd like to shorten the bibliography by combining entries of the same authors and years (but different articles) by using **biber**'s @set-function. If combining two bibliography entries (Bringmann.2005 and Bringmann.2005b to Bringmann_2005), the output looks like:

[image]

To shorten this a bit, the author-list of Bringmann.2005b should disappear.
Like:

G. Bringmann, A. J. Price Mortimer, P. A. Keller, M. J. Gresser, J. Garner, M. Breuning,
Angewandte Chemie International Edition **2005**, *44*, 5384–5427; Angewandte Chemie **2005**, *117*, 5518–5563.

My .bib-file is updated very often. Therefore, I combine one entryset.bib file (containing **@set-entries**; not beeing updated regularly) and one testbib.bib (containing all articles, books etc.; updated very often).

Here some code:

```
\documentclass[%
paper=A4,
twoside=true,
openright,
parskip=full,
chapterprefix=true,
11pt,
headings=normal,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc,
titlepage=on,
captions=tableabove,
draft=false,
]{scrreprt}%


\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=ascii,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\bibliography{entryset,testbib}



\begin{document}
This is the text.\cite{Bringmann_2005}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the *entryset.bib*-file looks like:

```
@Set{Bringmann_2005,
entryset = {Bringmann.2005, Bringmann.2005b},
}
```

the *testbib.bib*-file looks like:

```
@article{Bringmann.2005,
 author = {Bringmann, Gerhard and Price Mortimer, Anne J. and Keller, Paul A. and Gresser, Mary J. and Garner, James and Breuning, Matthias},
 year = {2005},
 title = {Atroposelective Synthesis of Axially Chiral Biaryl Compounds},
 pages = {5384--5427},
 volume = {44},
 number = {34},
 issn = {1433-7851},
 journal = {Angewandte Chemie International Edition},
 doi = {10.1002/anie.200462661}
}


@article{Bringmann.2005b,
 author = {Bringmann, Gerhard and Price Mortimer, Anne J. and Keller, Paul A. and Gresser, Mary J. and Garner, James and Breuning, Matthias},
 year = {2005},
 title = {Atropselektive Synthese axial-chiraler Biaryle},
 pages = {5518--5563},
 volume = {117},
 number = {34},
 issn = {00448249},
 journal = {Angewandte Chemie},
 doi = {10.1002/ange.200462661}
}
```

Is there a way to manipulate the @set entry or something else to fix this problem?
Thank you very much in advance, guys!

Greetings,
Bernd

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, `biblatex` already provides all the facilities to deal with this effectively (it still takes quite some code, though).

The `authortitle` bibliography style has an option to replace repeated authors in the list by a dash, we copy all the macros needed to do that and slightly modify one macro (namely `bbx:dashcheck`)

```
\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{}

\makeatletter
\InitializeBibliographyStyle{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbool{bbx@inset}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

\renewbibmacro*{begrelated}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}}

\renewbibmacro*{endrelated}{%
  \usebibmacro*{bbx:savehash}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    bool {bbx@inset}
    and
    not test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}}
    {#1}
    {#2}}
\makeatother
```

`biblatex` will now omit repeated (same) authors in `@set` entries.

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bringmann.2005,
 author = {Bringmann, Gerhard and Price Mortimer, Anne J. and Keller, Paul A. and Gresser, Mary J. and Garner, James and Breuning, Matthias},
 year = {2005},
 title = {Atroposelective Synthesis of Axially Chiral Biaryl Compounds},
 pages = {5384--5427},
 volume = {44},
 number = {34},
 issn = {1433-7851},
 journal = {Angewandte Chemie International Edition},
 doi = {10.1002/anie.200462661}
}


@article{Bringmann.2005b,
 author = {Bringmann, Gerhard and Price Mortimer, Anne J. and Keller, Paul A. and Gresser, Mary J. and Garner, James and Breuning, Matthias},
 year = {2005},
 title = {Atropselektive Synthese axial-chiraler Biaryle},
 pages = {5518--5563},
 volume = {117},
 number = {34},
 issn = {00448249},
 journal = {Angewandte Chemie},
 doi = {10.1002/ange.200462661}
}
@Set{Bringmann_2005,
entryset = {Bringmann.2005, Bringmann.2005b},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{}

\makeatletter
\InitializeBibliographyStyle{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbool{bbx@inset}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

\renewbibmacro*{begrelated}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}}

\renewbibmacro*{endrelated}{%
  \usebibmacro*{bbx:savehash}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{author}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{translator}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    bool {bbx@inset}
    and
    not test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}}
    {#1}
    {#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the text. \cite{Bringmann_2005,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,set,stdmodel}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how in [1] the author list is not repeated, because they coincide; while in [4] and [5] the (different) authors are retained. 
The repeated author in [2] and [3] is also retained in both entries.